# SciFi short story with space travel, alien artifacts, and drug therapy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember this story I read, but so far my google-fu is failing me.

The story had some people who worked on a space station that camped out near some magic point (maybe a Lagrange point?) in space where sometimes spaceships disappear/reappear.

When ships reappear, their pilot/crew is sometimes insane, but also sometimes have some piece of alien tech/artifact that is valuable to humanity.

The people working on the space station help the returning travelers re-acclimate to humanity and maybe stay sane through assorted drugs & therapy, and hopefully not commit suicide.

Is this ringing any bells for anyone? Did I just dream this?

Comment: "Gateway" by Fred Pohl?

Comment: Yes, it definitely sounds like a partially remembered *Gateway*, which gets asked about pretty frequently.  See here:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138354/looking-for-sci-fi-novel-i-read-about-humanity-finding-alien-station-on-orbit-of and the multiple linked duplicates from that question.

Comment: It's ringing loud bells for me, actually. But I'll have to check my library to answer conclusively; I'm thinking John Varley.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysterious contact by advanced aliens; leaves humans insane](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12017/mysterious-contact-by-advanced-aliens-leaves-humans-insane)

Comment: @fez My bad, I saw tsc_chazz "accept" it in the comment below the answer and thought that was the OP (SomeGuy).  My understanding of the dup close policy is that comments by the OP which "accept" the answer are allowed as many posters never come back to click the Accepted button.

Comment: @gowenfawr ah yes, I see what you mean, it does look like an accept via comment (you are 100% correct, it's as good as a green tick for closing)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is Hinterlands by William Gibson. A cosmonaut went missing in a particular point in space after lighting a flare, and came back 2 years later in a catatonic state, with a sea shell of alien origin.  The trip is replicated several times and people bring back various mysterious artifacts of alien origin, but everyone always comes back insane or dead.  A space station with a very nice natural looking environment is constructed, and staffed with specially trained people to talk to the returnees and try and keep them alive.  They also use a lot of drugs to keep the voyagers stable and happy enough to stay alive.

[Hinterlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinterlands_%28short_story%29?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: /me shakes tiny fist... Yes, that's the one I was thinking of.