# Short story about a point in the solar system where ships disappear and reappear with scientific break throughs

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find the title of a short story about astronauts being sent in ships to a point in the solar system (orbit of Jupiter?) where they disappear temporarily. When they return they have been given new knowledge (e.g the cure for cancer), but they don't live very long. The story is told from the point of view of someone waiting for a pilot to return,  ready to try and prevent thier death. Ring any bells?

Comment: When did you read this?  Was it in a hardcopy book/magazine or online?  If it was in a collection, do you remember any of the other stories?

Comment: We just had [a question about this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/286456/scifi-short-story-with-space-travel-alien-artifacts-and-drug-therapy) last week: "[Hinterlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinterlands_(short_story))" by William Gibson.

Comment: It’s definitely “Hinterlands”

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your posts if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)

Comment: Close voters please note that OP has not indicated, by acceptance, comment, or vote, that "Hinterlands" is correct.  (Even if we're certain it is.)

Answer (score 10):

This is [William Gibson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Gibson)'s 1981 short story "[Hinterlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinterlands_(short_story))", which was first published in [*Omni*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omni_(magazine)), but which is anthologized in [*Burning Chrome*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_Chrome).

The story features:

- A point in the solar system out near Jupiter where ships emitting a flare at with (if I recall correctly) hydrogen's spectral frequency, vanish to far reaches of the universe, and which return some time later.
- The people who return are either dead, or suicidal and uncommunicative.
- Returnees bear with them marvels: proof of extra-solar life forms, the key to curing cancer, etc.
- A narrative told from the point of view of someone not 'accepted' for the journey (i.e. they were sent out in a spaceship/capsule, but they did not vanish to parts of the remote universe).
- People who are not accepted serve as personalized care-givers for living returnees, to try to get them out of their suicidal funk.

[image: Paperback cover of Burning Chrome by William Gibson]